# worth the time investment to learn Qt (c++)?

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

i already know java, c++ (no one framework for GUI development) and little of c# (winforms for gui development) but i'm thinking to ivest my free time to learn Qt, what do you recommend me? has Qt a good future or not?

Comment: I'd say it's not a bad idea. QT has been out since the early 90's and is still pretty active. This may provide some insight: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/115045/good-c-gui-library-for-windows

EDIT: There's also Boost ^^

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think it's worth it.  We used Qt recently because it allowed us to make a cross-platform GUI that looks good on Linux, Windows, and Mac.  It's kind of a tough learning curve to figure out how to use the [QLayouts](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qlayout.html) correctly, but after you do your GUI will look great on many different platforms, with many different font sizes, and with many different window sizes.  I like how Qt allows you to make applications that use the native widgets with the native look and feel.  Applications built with Qt will look like they **belong** no matter what platform they are running on.  Another great feature is that the Qt framework is small enough that you can just include the Qt DLL files in your application's binary directory, so it simplifies the installation process for your application and makes life easier for everyone (no VMs to install, no 600 MB downloads).

I'd recommend using Qt directly from C++.  There are wrappers for it on many languages, but it's hard to believe those wrappers will support every feature and allow you to subclass Qt classes.

You can kind of make cross-platform GUIs with C# WinForms, using Mono on Linux and Mac.  But Mono's WinForms is not maintained, the results look really bad, and there are some crippling bugs on macOS.

Answer (score 6):

I can't say enough good things about Qt. Their documentation is bar-none. I've never seen more examples and better documentation that with Qt. It's the standard by which I judge ***all*** other frameworks. What's more, the Cross-Platform capabilities are amazing. You get native looking apps, all for free. I'd say go for it.

Comment: Yeah, the poor documentation is the principal fact that stop me to learn qt framework, i don't have too much experience with gui's (only swing of java and winforms of c#). In youtube are a very nice channel of Qt Tuts (the user that create that is "voidrealms") but no more tuts in all internet....maybe i need to wait what will happen with Qt because windows 8 is comming soon...Thanks!

Comment: @innuendoreplay, Qt poor documentation? It's one of the best documented frameworks there is !

Comment: @MartinBeckett I think he's trying to say the fact that other frameworks have such poor documentation has motivated him to use Qt.

Comment: Maybe i'm not being clear. @MartinBeckett yeah you have reason, Qt has well-done documentation (clean & elegant) but no more of the official docs. The fact is, the start point to learn Qt is only the book "C++ Qt Programming, 2nd Edition", i don't know about another resources. I usually go to documentation when i already know the the basics, but i don't know the basics of Qt right now.

Comment: Some of the tutorials provided on the official Qt Website are rather outdated, e.g. the one about QStyle, which uses a rather silly approach to using QStyle and doesn't use a lot of the really mighty features. The documentation of the library however is well-written.